# Handling html element chnages inside loop separately

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have a form with `*ngFor` loop which generates dynamically input angular ReactiveForm input fields. Each field has a click event which changes the view. But clicking to one element triggers of course another elements also. I need this behavior of changing type one of the input field, so the user can add custom value instead of choosing one of predefined.

[image]

To implement behavior of the gif above I've created following template and the method.

```
<div class="word-description-block" *ngFor="let control of wordForm.controls | keyvalue">
  <ion-item *ngIf="freeType">
    <ion-input placeholder="Define custom type"></ion-input>
    <ion-button size="small" slot="end" fill="clear" (click)="switchDescriptionInputType()">
      <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="redo"></ion-icon>
    </ion-button>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item button *ngIf="!freeType">
    <ion-select placeholder="Select Declension">
      <ion-select-option value="f">Female</ion-select-option>
      <ion-select-option value="m">Male</ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
    <ion-button size="small" slot="end" fill="clear" (click)="switchDescriptionInputType()">
      <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="create"></ion-icon>
    </ion-button>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-textarea rows="5" formControlName="coreWordDescription"
      placeholder="{{ 'ADD_WORD.description_help_text' | translate }}">
    </ion-textarea>
    <ion-button class="item-bottom-delete-button" size="small" slot="end" fill="clear">
      <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="trash"></ion-icon>
    </ion-button>
  </ion-item>
</div>
```

So `switchDescriptionInputType()` method just changes the value of `freeType`

```
// initializing freeType value as false
freeType = false;
switchDescriptionInputType() {
    this.freeType = !this.freeType;
}
```

How could be solved this issue? There can be hundred of this input fields.

Comment: Simple. Instead of a single flag variable i.e. `freeType`, use an array of flags for each input. I would suggest including an extra field in `wordForm.controls` so that you can manage the flags easily.

Comment: That's because you've just used a single property `freeType` to manage the Edit State of all the `FormGroup`s. You'll need an array that tracks the edit state of each item individually.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="word-description-block" *ngFor="let control of wordForm.controls | keyvalue">
  <ion-item *ngIf="control.freeType">
    <ion-input placeholder="Define custom type"></ion-input>
    <ion-button size="small" slot="end" fill="clear" (click)="control.freeType = !control.freeType">
      <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="redo"></ion-icon>
    </ion-button>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item button *ngIf="!control.freeType">
    <ion-select placeholder="Select Declension">
      <ion-select-option value="f">Female</ion-select-option>
      <ion-select-option value="m">Male</ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
    <ion-button size="small" slot="end" fill="clear" (click)="control.freeType = !control.freeType">
      <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="create"></ion-icon>
    </ion-button>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-textarea rows="5" formControlName="coreWordDescription"
      placeholder="{{ 'ADD_WORD.description_help_text' | translate }}">
    </ion-textarea>
    <ion-button class="item-bottom-delete-button" size="small" slot="end" fill="clear">
      <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="trash"></ion-icon>
    </ion-button>
  </ion-item>
</div>
```

Make sure `wordForm.controls` item has the field `freeType` with initial value set.

Comment: I have now `ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ngIf: true'. Current value: 'ngIf: false'.` error